# Почему таблицы b_search_content_stem, b_search_content_text, b_search_custom_rank, b_search_suggest ... пустые?

Tags: битрикс, sphinx

Таблицы пустые:

```
b_search_content_freq
b_search_content_stem
b_search_content_text
b_search_custom_rank
.b_search_stem
b_search_suggest
b_search_user_right
```

и что надо сделать, чтобы данные таблицы заполнились?
используется поиск на сфинксе.(галочки "При ранжировании результатов учитывать расстояние между словами", "При ранжировании результатов учитывать рейтинг" проставлены)

И за что отвечают данные таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждом инфоблоке есть настройки "Индексировать элементы для модуля поиска" вот если вам нужно что бы данные из конкретного инфоблока участвовали в поиске ее нужно включить.
Далее когда настроите инфоблоки нужно зайти в Настройки - Поиск - Переиндексация и сделать полную переиндексацию, после этого эти таблицы должны заполниться.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, дело в том я многократно индексировала ( в течение месяца), но эти таблицы не заполняются, а остальные таблицы заполняются...
Вот, например, полагаю мне нужна таблица b_search_content_stem или b_search_stem, чтобы поиск шел побуквенно в search.title
а у меня эти таблицы пустые, кроме остальных таблиц модуля search ( модуль удаляла, устанавливала, переиндексировала -результат нулевой)
Я экспортировала бд с рабочего сайта.

Comment: Смотрю проверку сайта - тестирование бд- везде стоит графа "успешно"
Проверка / восстановление таблиц -у каждой таблицы стоит статус "ОК"
А также инфоблок участвует в поиске...(стоят галки "Индексировать разделы для модуля поиска","Индексировать элементы для модуля поиска")

Comment: @RanMan в настройках модуля поиска, выберите bitrix и попробуйте проиндексировать сайт, посмотрите результат, если заработает то скорее всего дело в настройках sphinx или в самом sphinx движке

Comment: попробую,
а при сфинксе все таблицы модуля поиска должны заполняться?
вот у меня даже в конфиге сфинкса стемминг стоит.
min_stemming_len =3 
http://joxi.ru/BA0L6BDHJXpg8A

Comment: @RanMan вообще должны и заполняются, ни разу такой проблемы не возникало. Если заработает без сфинкса то нужно смотреть конфиг сфинкса

Comment: спасибо, без сфинкса под bitrix заполняются таблицы..., но я никак не пойму, что у меня неправильно в конфиге http://joxi.ru/BA0L6BDHJXpg8A, ведь ищется...

Вы можете прислать рабочий конфиг, если нетрудно,  спасибо...

Comment: @RanMan https://yadi.sk/d/eB1LBX0BgeA5wA конфиг с рабочего сайта, поменяйте path на свой и проверьте что настройки сфинкса в битриксе верные порты и схема подключения.

Comment: спасибо огромное, это вроде стандартный конфиг...Возможно, мне показалось...
Попробую еще раз (я делала ранее таким конфигом, выдавал идентичный рез-т, что данные таблицы не заполнены)
какая версия у Вас сфинкса? ( Может, у вас раньше стоял метод поиска битрикс, а потом сменили на метод "сфинкс", и все таблицы остались заполненными?)
Может, так поможет? (а я удаляла модуль поиска и устанавливала перед сфинксом). И у Вас ищет по части слова под сфинксом? А то есть информация в сети от 16года, что якобы битрикс не ищет по части слова при включенном морфологическом поиске?)

Comment: возможно эти таблицы заточенны под стемминг,а у меня лемматизация в конфиге сфинкса прописана... Может , поэтому, не заполняются таблички.
А битрикс лемматизацию поддерживает? 
А версия модуля поиска какая у вас?Скажите, пож-ста,если нетрудно...

Comment: также с таким конфигом... http://joxi.ru/xAenYxaHpqagNr

Comment: @RanMan конфиг этот с интернет магазина на 5 миллионов товаров, стандартный поиск просто напросто не работает с таким количеством данных, по этому я использовал сфинкс и индексируются документы тоже через него, стоит VMBitrix 7.1.0 на нем Sphinx 2.2.11 конфиг я вам скидывал, модуль поиска 17.0.1 включены настройки https://yadi.sk/i/LxrfISvlIhbukQ
https://yadi.sk/i/OhfiSbEFowhnTw
https://yadi.sk/i/u22AlOcx67Y5cw
в итоге получаем поиск как нам нужно вот такие таблицы он заполняет https://yadi.sk/i/pkdEqZy57SmNcg

Comment: спасибо Вам большое за подробное объяснение!!!
Очень благодарна, буду пробовать...

Comment: все тоже самое...
не заполняются данные таблицы...
http://freesmska.ru/kak-ya-lechil-poisk-v-bitrix-versiya-modulya-11-0-6/ -не помогло....
Странно, почему так получается...